# How to pass objects as arguments?

Tags: c++, function, class, friend, borland-c++

I have changed the code here
all the variables have to remain private and using friend functions is a requirement.
Here there are two classes A and B and I am supposed to accept 5 numbers(void enter()).The function average is to be able to access all variables and give the average.
I know that currently the line

```
 obj2.average(a,b,c,d,e);
```

will give an error as the variables are not accessible
so my question is, how do I pass the variables in the last line?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class A
{
 int a;
 int b;

 public:
 friend class B;
 int enter1()
 {
  cout<<"enter the value of a and b"<<endl;
  cin>>a>>b;
  return(a,b);
 }
};

class B
{
 int c;
 int d;
 int e;

 public:
 void average(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
 {
 float avg;
 avg=((a+b+c+d+e)/5);
 cout<<"average is "<<avg<<endl;
 }

 int enter()
 {
 cout<<"enter the value of c,d,e"<<endl;
 cin>>c>>d>>e;
 return(c,d,e);
 }
 };

void main()
{
 A obj1;
 B obj2;
 obj1.enter1();
 obj2.enter();
 obj2.average(obj1.a,obj1.b,obj2.c,obj2.d,obj2.e);
}
```

Comment: `obj1.a` is not a valid function argument name in C++ (which this seems to be, despite you not tagging it as such)

Comment: Also neither `obj1` nor `obj2` are declared in the scope of `enter` (and you are using the wrong operator for input after the first one)

Comment: Can you extract a [mcve] from your code and post that instead? As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please also post the full error message in the body of the question

Comment: `void average(A obj1.a, A obj1.b, B obj2.c, B obj2.d, B obj2.e) {}` - This looks wrong. You don't need the `obj.`

Comment: thank you for all the suggestions.I have implemented the ones I could and have changed the code a decent amount.I am also new to friend functions so I am not sure if these errors are because of that to a certain extent.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` Are you using Turbo C++ by any chance?

Comment: its on borland C++ version 5.02 I think

Comment: OT: Are you aware that Borland C++ 5.02 was replaced with Borland C++ Builder in **1997** and that C++ *"was initially standardized in **1998** as ISO/IEC 14882:1998, which was then amended by the C++03, C++11 and C++14 standards. The current C++17 standard supersedes these with new features and an enlarged standard library."* [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)?

Comment: It's nearly a quarter century old piece of software. If you are not coerced to use it by your school, you may want to throw it away and start anew with a modern compiler and a modern C++ book.

Comment: yeah we are required to use it actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access member variables in the main function because they are private.
You can send the first instance to the method as a parameter, then use the class A member variables inside the method.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{
 int a;
 int b;

 public:
 friend class B;
 int enter1()
 {
  cout<<"enter the value of a and b"<<endl;
  cin>>a>>b;
  return(a,b);
 }
};

class B
{
 int c;
 int d;
 int e;

 public:
 void average(A obj)
 {
 float avg;
 avg=((obj.a+obj.b+c+d+e)/5);
 cout<<"average is "<<avg<<endl;
 }

 int enter()
 {
 cout<<"enter the value of c,d,e"<<endl;
 cin>>c>>d>>e;
 return(c,d,e);
 }
 };

int main()
{
 A obj1;
 B obj2;
 
 obj1.enter1();
 obj2.enter();
obj2.average(obj1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks you for taking time out.I tried your answer as well and that worked out great too!!

Answer (score 0):

> Here there are two classes A and B and I am supposed to accept 5 numbers(void enter()).

The two shown classes have two member functions (`enter1` and `enter`), both returning an `int` (instead of beeing `void`, if I've understood the problem statement), but probably the "wrong" one.

```
int enter()
{
    cout << "enter the value of c,d,e" << endl;
    cin >> c >> d >> e;
    // The variable c, d and e here, are the private members of class B
    // If we assume that all the values are correctly extracted from the input stream 
    // (we shouldn't, but for the sake of simplicity let's do it), those member variables
    // are now set and there's no need to "return" them.
    
    return (c,d,e);
    //     ^^^^^^^     The ',' here, is the comma operator(1). 
    //                 This is equivalent to 
    //    return e;
}
```

> all the variables have to remain private and using friend functions is a requirement.

In the posted snippet, the entire class `B` is declared as `friend` of class `A`, instead of only some functions. That may be a way to accomplish the task, but it doesn't seem to fulfill the requirements.

The function which calculates the average is declared as a public member of class `B`

```
void average(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    float avg;
    avg = ((a + b + c + d + e) / 5);
    //                         ^      This is an INTEGER division, beeing the result of
    // the sum and the literal 5 both integral types, it produces a TRUNCATED integer result
    // which is only after converted to a float.
    // ...
}
```

It is (erroneously) called in `main` like this

```
obj2.average(obj1.a, obj1.b, obj2.c, obj2.d, obj2.e);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   Those are all PRIVATE members,
//                                                    invisible from 'main'
```

> How to pass objects as arguments?

One way to meet all the requirements could be to declare `average` as a free function, friend of both classes (to have access to their private members), expecting two arguments of type const reference to class A and B.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/9d7haf) is a possible implementation, not necessarily the best design.

<sup>(1) [The built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)</sup>

Comment: thank you for taking time out and answering.your suggestions worked wonderfully